# unable to make a regular expression using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a regular expression for my university registration number. I am 75% successful to make it. I'm new and i don't know how to make it. This is what i am doing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<body>

<script>
str = "l1s10bscs"; //successfully tested
                   //but i want to append any 4 digits at the end of l1s10bscs

re = /[a-zA-Z]\d{1}[s|S|f|F]\d{2}[bscs]/g;

result = re.test(str);

document.write(result);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

i tried this but it doesn't work.

```
re = /[a-zA-Z]\d{1}[s|S|f|F]\d{2}[bscs][0-9]{4}/g;  // this doesn't work
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to match. Can you give us a set of strings that should match your regex?

Comment: 1: l1s10bscs2034
2: L1F10BSCS1111

it should work well with these sort of strings.

Comment: Why are you using `[0-9]{4}` instead of `\d{4}`?

Comment: So "bscs" should always be in the string in exactly that order?

Comment: You might want to put that down as an answer, @AmericanUmlaut. The previous one had a match even though it only matched the first single character in the "bscs" part of the string.

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut bscs should always be in this order. But the digits can be changed in the string as i want to check different Registration numbers.

Comment: Try his answer, it should work. Note the /i for making it case independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/[a-z]\d[sf]\d{2}bscs\d{4}/i
```

According to your description, this should fit.

I changed the following:

- [bscs] means "b or s or c or s" (so "b or s or c", the extra s is meaningless). You wanted just the literal four-character string "bscs"
- \d{1} is the same as \d - this isn't an error, but there's no reason to explicity define a character as occurring only once.
- You have a \g flag but no \i, so you'll match the string you're looking for multiple times inside of a larger string, but your search isn't case insensitive.
- [s|S|f|F] means "s or | or S or |..." You meant "s or S or f...", which is written [sSfF].
- Since \i is used to make a search case insensitive, I simplified [sSfF] to [sf]

Comment: Do you need to match the bscs? Wouldn't omitting the `()` work just as well?

Comment: @Guvante You're right, the parentheses aren't necessary. I actually like them because they clearly delineate the substring, but I've omitted them to make the regex as simple as possible.

Comment: `[s|f]` means `"s" OR "|" OR "f"`.  Shouldn't that be `[sf]` or `(s|f)`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yep. Fixed. Also, I just realized that there's no reason to explicitly define {1} for the first digit.

Comment: Better review it thoroughly before next edit before it becomes community wiki :)

Comment: You don't need `A-Z` since you have the `i` modifier.

Comment: @owlstead: Why would it become community wiki?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut, if i have three or four strings like (bscs). Should i be using the same methodology again??

Comment: @RocketHazmat "The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner."

Comment: @owlstead: It was only edited 3 times (you have a 5 minute grace period after an edit).

Comment: @AmericanUmlaut, i have just made another RE for email address. Here it is `re = /[a-z0-9][@]((yahoo)|(hotmail)|(gmail))[.]((com)|(co.uk))/i;` Is it a good practice to make REs this way?? It is working and i know to make it better i have to add special characters

Comment: @dEvILsadVocAte: You don't need to use `[]` for just one character.

Comment: @owlstead Yeah, sorry about the constant editing :-/. I need to stop feeling the need to hit the "post" button before I've given my answers the same consideration I'd give code I'm about to check in in real life.

Comment: @dEvILsadVocAte I'm not an expert on regex best practices, but I'd give the following feedback on the above: As Rocket Hazmat said, wrapping single characters in [] is meaningless. You're excluding lots of legal characters (eg , . - _) from the local part of the address (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address). Technically the local part of an e-mail address - but not the domain - is case sensitive, though I think it's very common to treat it as insensitive. You won't recognize googlemail.com, even though that's equivalent to gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

The `[bscs]` needs to not be in square brackets: square brackets means `b` or `s` or `c` or `s`.  It works without the number because it matches "l1s10b", but the next character is not a digit so looking for 4 digits fails.  Try this:

```
re = /[a-zA-Z]\d{1}[s|S|f|F]\d{2}bscs[0-9]{4}/g;
```

Comment: `[s|S|f|F]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Yep, you are right, the `|` characters do not belong in there.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing `[]` and `()`.

`()` creates a group, whereas `[]` means "match any letter from inside".

`[s|S|f|F]` means `'s' OR '|' OR 'S' OR 'f' OR 'F'`.  That should be `(s|S|f|F)` or `[sSfF]`.

NOTE: You can use the `i` modifier to make it case-insensitive.

```
re = /[a-z]\d[sf]\d{2}bscs\d{4}/gi;
```

Comment: Good point on the `|` in the `[]`.  It may or may not be acceptable to make the entire match case-insensitive though.

Comment: @RocketHazmat i have another question. What if i want to restrict a character like hyphen '-' in my email address RE, what should i do then?

Comment: i mean an email add can be of type alphanumeric but it cannot have  some other characters in email like hyphen '-', semicolon ';' and coma ','. How to restrict them in RE?

Comment: @dEvILsadVocAte: Inside `[]` the `^` character means "not".  For example `[^;]` is "any character that isn't `;`".